# IOS7 translucent keyboard not working

Tags: keyboard, ios7, xcode5

OK, so I've searched the web, Rebuilt my xcode 4.6.3 project in xcode 5, Set my Base SDK to IOS7, Changed my Deployment Target to 7.0, and my keyboard still has the generic gray background.
  I've deployed to my IPAD 2 running IOS7, and to the simulator for iPhone Retina (4-inch 64-bit).
Still no luck.

The keyboard auto pops up when I click on a text box.  I've tried changing the Appearance (Under Keyboard) in the storyboard from Default to Light, but still no luck.

Where is transparent keyboard setting hiding?

Comment: i've found `self.txtTest.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert;` in viewDidLoad but I thought IOS7 had a different way.

Comment: Thanks, like you I struggled figuring out how to get this to work. However, it looks like something they over-looked.